# how to foreach into the same foreach on .net core razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

how to foreach on this

how to foreach into the same foreach on .net core razor page
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnS8g.jpg

my project is asp.netCore razor page5

Comment: Please post the actual code, not a link to an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use foreach into a foreach,here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class ProductQueryModel {
        public List<string> MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    foreach (var item1 in item.MyProperty)
    {
        <div>@item1</div>
    }
}
```